# impossible to add extensions on nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to add 3 extension to nifi (nifi-encryptMD5-nar-1.0.nar-unpacked,nifi-getOperator-nar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar-unpacked,nifi-splitAttributeValue-nar-1.0.nar-unpacked)

I added the extensions folder in the directory /opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/work/nar/extensions/

then when I restart the nifi service, nifi turns off and does not turn on, when I force the start with the user nifi, nifi turns on but the extentions have been deleted from the directory /opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/work/nar/extensions/

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#autoloading-processors

Comment: As @daggett pointed, put `nar` files at `/lib` directory. After putting the files there, if NiFi is not able to start, then check NiFi logs for any exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put `*.nar` packages into `nifi/lib` directory.

nifi will extract it automatically on startup into `nifi/work` folder.

Answer (score 3):

As daggett says, you need to use the .nar files, not any unpacked directories.

In your nifi.properties there will be two or more properties that provide locations for NiFi libraries:

```
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.library.directory.<something>=./<yourdir>
```

The first is the default and contains all the basic NiFi files. It is only checked on startup and any valid nars found are unpacked in the work directory and loaded. Generally you don't want to add anything here except in test environments as it complicates upgrades.

The second is empty by default but it is scanned every 30 seconds for new .nars. These will be unpacked and loaded if possible, but only for new libraries. Already loaded libraries will **not** be reloaded.
This is a good location to add your validated custom libraries without having to restart NiFi.

The third and further need to be added manually to the properties file. These are loaded on startup only and useful if you have a lot of custom processors and want to keep them organized.

In your situation I'd put the .nars in the extensions folder and check the logs to see if they were loaded successfully. You'll then need a **full refresh of the browser window** (Shift+F5 I think) before they show up in the list of processors.

In a cluster setup, add the .nars on all nodes and verify their availability before trying to add them to the canvas or things might get messy.